# How to convert attribs to object in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, react-native, object

I am struggling to convert these html attributes I extracted from widget tag to an object so I can change some of its values. Following are the attributes.

```
widget="fixtures" competition="1" season="2020" match="123" template="cell" live="true" sport="hockey"
```

What I have tried is JSON.stringify and JSON.parse but nothing seems to be working.

This is what I have done, the ending result seems like object but when I try to access one of any key from it I get undefined.

```
htmlAttribs = htmlAttribs.replace(/[=]/g, ':');
htmlAttribs = htmlAttribs.replace(/[ ]/g, ', ');
htmlAttribs = `{${htmlAttribs}}`;
htmlAttribs = JSON.stringify(htmlAttribs);     
htmlAttribs = JSON.parse(htmlAttribs);
console.log(htmlAttribs);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
htmlAttribs = htmlAttribs.replace(/[=]/g, ':');
htmlAttribs = htmlAttribs.replace(/[ ]/g, ', ');

const obj = eval('({' + htmlAttribs + '})');
```

One can access values using object.key_name

Comment: Please try and avoid using `eval` where possible! I appreciate that it might not always be possible but it's definitely dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

I would split each of the attributes on an empty space `' '` then use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to build up an object setting each property and value.

```js
const htmlAttribs = `widget="fixtures" competition="1" season="2020" match="123" template="cell" live="true" sport="hockey"`;

const attribs = htmlAttribs
  .split(' ')
  .reduce((prev, curr) => {
    const [key, value] = curr.split('=');
    prev[key] = value.replaceAll('"', '');
    return prev;
  }, {});
  
console.log(attribs);
```

Results in an object looking like:

```
{
  "widget": "fixtures",
  "competition": "1",
  "season": "2020",
  "match": "123",
  "template": "cell",
  "live": "true",
  "sport": "hockey"
}
```

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'value.replaceAll')

Comment: Have you got an attribute that has no value by any chance? The code works with the example you gave us!

Comment: Yeah, it is making issue with attributes from backend(long long string), but it is showing correct results with hard coded(above) data, so maybe yes, there might be some issue with attributes. Thanks